# MVC3 query clause custom query

Tags: c#, linq

```
First Table
+--------+------------+-------+
| type   | variety    | price |
+--------+------------+-------+
| apple  | gala       |  2.79 | 
| apple  | fuji       |  0.24 | 
| apple  | limbertwig |  2.87 | 
| orange | valencia   |  3.59 | 
| orange | navel      |  9.36 | 
| pear   | bradford   |  6.05 | 
| pear   | bartlett   |  2.14 | 
| cherry | bing       |  2.55 | 
| cherry | chelan     |  6.33 | 
+--------+------------+-------+
```

```
Second Table
+--------+----------+
| type   | minprice |
+--------+----------+
| apple  |     0.24 | 
| cherry |     2.55 | 
| orange |     3.59 | 
| pear   |     2.14 | 
+--------+----------+
```

```
select type, min(price) as minprice
from fruits
group by type;
```

The first table is and example of the data that I have and the second table is what I want to get from the first.

I am using `GenericRepository/UnitOfwork` to get the data from repository.

```
repository.fruitRepository.Get().GroupBy(m => m.type);
```

But I can only get the type field but I want to get more fields.

Do I need to use a select clause before groupby?  If yes, how can I select more fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GroupBy method returns more data, but it's returned as an enumerable... you may be able to pull what you want out of it with a Select after the GroupBy...

```
repository.fruitRepository.Get()
    .GroupBy(m => m.type)
    .Select(m => new { type = m.Key, minPrice = m.Min(f => f.Price) });
```

Or if you prefer a LINQ statement:

```
var result = from x in repository.fruitRepository.Get()
             group x by x.type into typeGroup
             select new
             {
                 type = typeGroup.Key,
                 minPrice = typeGroup.Min(item => item.Price)
             };
```